# Verificar se usuário é administrador - WORDPRESS php

Tags: php, wordpress

/* VERIFICA LOGIN ON ------------------------*/

```
    global $current_user;

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_info = get_userdata($current_user->ID);

    $first_name = $user_info->first_name;
    $user_email = $user_info->user_email;
    $meta_value = $user_info->$meta_value;      




    if (in_array("administrator", $meta_value)) {

echo "é administrador"; } else { 

        echo "não é administrador";

     } ?>
```

mas não sei onde está o erro.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quiser verificar se o usuário atual é adiministrador, você pode usar a função `current_user_can('administrator')` que vai retornar `true` caso o usuário seja um adiministrador.

Answer (score -1):

A resposta do Gabriel é correta. Eu queria só fazer um comentário (mas não tenho pontos suficientes para tal):

Como este é um fórum para desenvolvedores, faz sentido colocar o link e explicar a função, até para que possam utilizar com outros roles (e capabilities).

Documentação da função: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can

Forma de utilização da função:

```
<?php current_user_can( $capability , $object_id ); ?>
```

Onde `$capability` pode ser o *role* (função que exerce - *administrator*, *subscriber*) ou uma *capability* (função que realiza - *publish_posts*, *activate_plugins*). E o `$object_id` é opcional e só recomendado quando verificando *meta capabilities*.

Exemplos:

```
if( current_user_can('administrator') ) {
    //ações a tomar se usuário é adiministrador
}

$ativador_de_plugin = current_user_can('activate_plugins');
```